# Magento error : when creating attribute

Tags: error, eav-attributes

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bikeplus`.`eav_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTITY_TYPE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CA), query was: INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` () VALUES ()
```

Plz, list all table are affected by `eav_attribute`.

Comment: at least show us your code...

Answer (score 0):

```
**eav_entity_type** is the table where all the entities 
are define based on that you will come to know the related tables of eav.

 For example your **entiy_type** code is **catalog_product** or entiy_type is 4 
you will come to know all the attributes of the above entity type in 
following table (**eav_attribute**) From there ther will be multiple tables 
related based on the following column (**backend_type**) in eav_attribute table.
According to type from **eav_entity_type** the folowing table 
(**catalog_eav_attribute**) and consider backend_type is int the following table 
will have effect  (**catalog_product_entity_int**)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is magento2 you can solve to follow the below process.

Please reset the product attribute indexer.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_attribute
```

Then run the entire reindex process

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I hope it will help you.